# Naming MapReduce job's part-0000 file to that of the input file in hadoop

Tags: hadoop, mapreduce

I have developed a code that runs a map reduce job to read files from FTP server and write it into `HDFS`. Into `HDFS` it writes the file from FTP into the specified output directory naming it as part-0000. In case I have multiple files on the FTP server I get all of them written to that one part-0000 file in `HDFS`.

To avoid this I plan to pass the name of the file as key along with the data as value . Thus the reducer gets the data into an output file with the key as the name of the file.

I understand that I have to use an `outputformat` that extends `MultipleTextOutputFormat`. I have written it as follows

```
 static class MultiFileOutput extends MultipleTextOutputFormat<Text, Text> {

         protected String generateFileNameForKeyValue(Text key, Text value,String name) {
            System.out.println("key is :"+ key.toString());
         System.out.println("value is :"+ value.toString());
            System.out.println("name is :"+ name.toString());

                 return key.toString();
         }
```

But I fail to pass the name of the input file being processed . How do I get the name of the input file ?

```
map.input.file
```

and

```
FileSystem fs = file.getFileSystem(conf);
                String fileName=fs.getName();
```

do not return the name of the input file.
 
Any pointers ?

Comment: After some working around I have figured out a few things and now my problem narrows down to this one step , how to get the name of the input file in the input directory being processed ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I used `FileStatus` object in the following code as my customised input format would not split the input file. It worked fine for me ..

```
 FileSystem fs = file.getFileSystem(conf);
                    FileStatus status= fs.getFileStatus(file);
                    String fileName=status.getPath().toString();
```

Answer (score 0):

You can get the input file path through context.

```
FileSplit fileSplit = (FileSplit) context.getInputSplit();
String inputFilePath = fileSplit.getPath().toString();
```

This will give the full path. If you want just the filename you can do this :

```
String inputFileName = fileSplit.getPath().getName();
```

HTH